# React Useeffect running when page loads

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

Am using useEffect in a react functional component to fetch data from an external API but it keeps calling the API endpoint on render on the page .
Am looking for a way to stop the useeffect from running on render on the component

Comment: Declare Empty array in the dependency.
Ex : `useEffect(() => somefunction(), [])`

Answer (score 3):

Use the dependency array (second argument to the `useEffect`), so you can specify when you need to run the `useEffect`.

The problem here is that you have not used the dependency array, so that it executes every time. By adding a dependency array, you specify the changes where you want `useEffect` to run.

```
useEffect(()=>{
},[<dependency array: which contains the properties>]);
```

If you leave the dependency array empty, it will run only once. Therefore if you want the API call to run only once, add an empty array as the second argument to your `useEffect`. This is your solution.

Like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   //Your API Call
},[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` is always meant to run after all the changes or render effects are update in the DOM. It will not run while or before the DOM is updated. You may not have given the second argument to `useEffect`, which if u do not provide will cause the `useEffect` to execute on each and every change. Assuming you only want to call the API just once when on after the first render you should provide an empty array.

**Runs on all updates, see no second argument to `useEffect`:**

```
useEffect(() => { /* call API */ });
```

**Runs when the prop or state changes, see the second argument:**

```
useEffect(() => { /* call API */ }, [prop, state]);
```

**Runs only once, see the empty second argument:**

```
useEffect(() => { /* call API */ }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read the full documentation about the [React useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Here is a easy example of using `useEffect`

```js
function functionalComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }, []); // it's necessary to use [] to avoid the re-rendering

  return <React.Fragment>
    {data !== null && (
      <React.Fragment>
        {data.results.map(data => (
          <div>
            {data.gender}
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>;
}
```

Maybe in your `useEffect` implementation you are avoiding the [] dependencies, this is a bit hard to understand if you come from class states. This on hooks review when a state element inside the hook change, for example if you are using an element that always change like a prop that you pass throught another component you might be setting inside the dependencies or another state, if you do not need any dependency just use it empty like the example above. As you can see in the documentation sometimes the dependencies are not used, this might generate an infinite loop.